# How to make custom EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, attributes, android-custom-view

[image]

I am trying to make custom `EditText` Something look like this.
Currently i am using Custom View Inheriting from `ConstraintLayout`

**DefaultEditTextContainerView.java**

```
public class DefaultEditTextContainerView extends ConstraintLayout
{
        @BindView(R.id.titleText)
        public TextView titleText;
        @BindView(R.id.contentEditText)
        public EditText contentEditText;

        private String mTitleText;
        private String mHintText;


        public DefaultEditTextContainerView(Context context) {
                super(context);
                init(null, 0);
        }

        public DefaultEditTextContainerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
                init(attrs, 0);

        }

        public DefaultEditTextContainerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
                init(attrs, defStyleAttr);

        }


        private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_default_edit_text_container_view,
                        this);
                ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

                //region Load attributes
                final TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(
                        attrs, R.styleable.DefaultEditTextContainerView, defStyle, 0);

                if (typedArray.hasValue(R.styleable.DefaultEditTextContainerView_titleText)) {
                        mTitleText = typedArray.getString(
                                R.styleable.LandingPageSectionItemView_titleText);
                }

                if (typedArray.hasValue(R.styleable.DefaultEditTextContainerView_hintText)) {
                        mHintText = typedArray.getString(
                                R.styleable.DefaultEditTextContainerView_hintText);
                }


                typedArray.recycle();
                // endregion


                titleText.setText(mTitleText);
                contentEditText.setHint(mHintText);
        }



}
```

**view_default_edit_text_container_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxHeight="100dp">


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@color/colorLight"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout10"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="필드 이름"
        android:textColor="@color/textLightDark"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/contentEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="예) 힌트 텍스트"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textLightDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorLight"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="99dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="271dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But the problem is, I have to access more than 5 attributes that are assigned to EditText. So i thought my CustomView Should Inherit from EditText. And that's what i am trying to do...

how can i inherit from EditText And create the same looking view as above?

OR

how can i Access all EditText Attributes from xml not specifing and overriding attributes via attr.xml ...

thank you!

===Edit==
what i want

```
ParentView(ConstraintLayout)
- ViewA(TextView)
- ViewB(EditText)
```

want to make a view looks like that but inherit from ViewB(EditText)
so i can mainly access to EditText's attributes

Comment: @ADM this is just an example. im not tring to make TextInputLayout thing...

Comment: So i guess i did not get your example . What exactly you want ? can you add the expected output (in english pls).

Answer (score 0):

From your mockup which shows the desired result,you might like this library to achieve this easily:https://github.com/HITGIF/TextFieldBoxes.I have used this library before and it is pretty easy to implement.

Here is the preview of the output the library gives:
[image]